# Accumulate the grouped sum of values across trillions of values

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a data reduction issue that is proving to be very difficult to solve.

Essentially, I have a program that calculates incremental values (floating point) for pairs of keys from a set of about 60 million keys total. The program will generate values for about 53 *trillion* pairs 'relatively' quickly (simply iterating through the values would take about three days ). Not every pair of keys will occur, and many pairs will come up many times. There is no reasonable way to have the pairs come up in a particular order. **What I need is a way to find the sum of the values generated for each pair of keys**.

For data that would fit in memory, this is a very simple problem. In python it would look something like:

```py
from collections import Counter
res = Counter()
for key1,key2,val in data_generator():
    res[(key1,key2)] += val
```

The problem, of course, is that a mapping like that won't fit in memory. So I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently with a mix of on-disk and in-memory processing.

So far I've tried:

1. A postgresql table with upserts (`ON CONFLICT UPDATE`). This turned out to be far, far to slow.
2. A hybrid of in-memory dictionaries in python that write to a [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/) or [LMDB](https://www.symas.com/lmdb) key value store when they get too big. Though these DBs are much faster than postgresql for this kind of task, the time to complete is still on the order of months.

At this point, I'm hoping someone has a better approach that I could try. Is there a way to break this problem up into smaller parts? Is there a standard MapReduce approach to this kind of problem?

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**
The computer I'm using has 64GB of RAM, 96 cores (most of my work is very parallelizable), and terabytes of HDD (and some SSD) storage.

It's hard to estimate the total number of key pairs that will be in the reduced result, but it will certainly be at least in the hundreds of billions.

Comment: This seems like a classic example of a MapReduce problem.   You're doing a word count of a large text, but your "words" are tuples.

Comment: Have you considered the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module?

Comment: This is a good point, but the big difference is that the 'reduced' result is still much too big for memory. This is the issue that is really making the problem hard. Essentially I need to be able to do very fast random lookups/updates on a larger-than-memory data structure.

Comment: How many unique key-pairs are you expecting in the final result? How much RAM and disk space do you have available to solve the problem?

Comment: @user3386109 Good questions. I've edited the main question with the info. Short answer: at least 100s of millions of unique key pairs, 64GB of ram, plenty of disk space.

Comment: @martineau I don't think shelve or other serialization approaches will fit the bill here, as I need to keep accessing the data to update the key-pair values.

Comment: If keys are mapped to 32-bit numbers, and the value is a 64-bit double precision floating point number, then minimum storage needed for a `(key1,key2,value)` tuple is 16 bytes, so the result easily fits into 64GB. It's just a question of whether you can do this with python, or whether you need a more memory efficient language like C.

Comment: @user3386109 What's the memory overhead for the 'index' (e.g. B+ tree) for the key lookup in something like C? (I did try this with python dictionaries first and it very quickly ran out of memory.)

Comment: @user3386109 Oh sorry I responded in a rush and misspoke. There will likely be hundreds of *billions* of keys

Comment: The index is the key-pair which takes 8 bytes (two 32-bit numbers), and the link to the lower level node is 8 bytes (64-bit pointers). At the leaf level, each leaf is the key-pair plus the value. So roughly 32 bytes per key-pair for the lowest two levels of the tree. Estimate 16 bytes per key-pair for higher level tree nodes, and another 16 bytes of overhead for memory management, and you're up to 64 bytes for each key-pair in the result, which allows hundreds of millions of unique key-pairs, but not billions.

Comment: Yeah, 100s of billions is a different story. In fact, 100s of billions brings into question whether terabytes of disk space is sufficient. Using 16-bytes per key-pair with 500 billion key-pairs requires 8 terabytes of storage, even with zero overhead.

Comment: Are we to assume that calculating values on the fly, as needed (rather than storing them) is not a viable solution? Does the distribution enquiries by key-pair lend itself to dynamically caching the values of the N key-pairs for which the frequency of enquiries is greatest? Are you perchance an astronomer?

Comment: What does `data_generator` do?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess at what you might be up to and suggest that, if you're trying to find the top all-pairs dot products of a sparse matrix, then [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01054) might be relevant to your interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frank Yellin observes, there's a one-round MapReduce algorithm. The mapper produces key-value pairs with key `key1,key2` and value `val`. The MapReduce framework groups these pairs by key (the shuffle). The reducer sums the values.

In order to control the memory usage, MapReduce writes the intermediate data to disk. Traditionally there are `n` files, and all of the pairs with key `key1,key2` go to file `hash((key1,key2)) mod n`. There is a tension here: `n` should be large enough that each file can be handled by an in-memory map, but if `n` is too large, then the file system falls over. Back of the envelope math suggests that `n` might be between 1e4 and 1e5 for you. Hopefully the OS will use RAM to buffer the file writes for you, but make sure that you're maxing out your disk throughput or else you may have to implement buffering yourself. (There also might be a suitable framework, but you don't have to write much code for a single machine.)

I agree with user3386109 that you're going to need a Really Big Disk. If you can regenerate the input multiple times, you can trade time for space by making k passes that each save only a 1/k fraction of the files.

I'm concerned that the running time of this MapReduce will be too large relative to the mean time between failures. MapReduce is traditionally distributed for fault tolerance as much as parallelism.

If there's anything you can tell us about how the input arises, and what you're planning to do with the output, we might be able to give you better advice.